# Accessing a particular table in MySQL database with php & c#

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql, database

I am using a MySQL DB to save game's highscores and then load them in my game.

Actually, I only had one game, so I had my database and one table in, which contains "name" and "score" rows.

Now, since I have another game, I created another table in my database (with another name but same properties) to save the new scores in this one.

But when I try to save my scores, they are saving in the old table and not the new one.

How can I control which table I acess to ?

EDIT :

http://puu.sh/b9rAn/5f0ac6c2ba.png
Here is my c# script when I submit my scores
http://puu.sh/b9qTV/6c8fef9423.png 
Here is my SaveScore script

Comment: Please include relevant info like how you connect to the database in each and the names of the tables and which table goes with which environment.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, I am new to this. I got two php scripts, SaveScore & LoadScore. When I submit my scores in the game, I setup the connexion informations in my C# game script and load the SaveScore.php which is on my FTP (I put it with FileZilla on my site).

My tables are named : "scores" for the first game (the one I won't use) and "LD30 scores" for the second one, the one I am trying to access.

Comment: Post your code that isn't working please

Comment: So, here is my SaveScore script:

http://puu.sh/b9qTV/6c8fef9423.png

host, base and password are still the same.
I thought the table was found in the query line, but changing "scores" didn't work.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_number_2` and not the other table.

Comment: Ow ! 
I can't test it now since my ISP is bugging (I guess there is a maintenance), but I think this : http://puu.sh/b9s8V/ba3f494a4f.png should work now :)

Thank you guys for your answers, that was so quick ! Good bye